# Did France flood Guinea with counterfeit currency to destabilize it?

Tags: history, france, africa, currency

I've read in several Pan-Africanist and conspiracy theory sources (e.g. [here](https://www.africanexponent.com/post/9746-poverty-in-freedom-when-france-almost-sparked-a-civil-war-in-france) and [here](https://www.globalresearch.ca/real-fake-helicopter-money-cia-counterfeiting-currencies-to-destroy-national-economies/5606034)) that France during the Fifth Republic smuggled in counterfeit Guinean Franc into Guinea in order to destabilize its economy after it gained independence.

I couldn't track this claim down to a reliable source, is there any truth in this?

Comment: Can you quote the actual claims here? The first link has someone making a claim, the second link has not - it just links to a 46 minutes Youtube video.

Comment: The second link has an actual claim that's just one line long. The proof would presumably be somewhere deep in that video.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, this actually happened, according to French journalists Roger Faligot and Pascal Krop, both of whom were mainstream journalists and specialized in French counterinsurgency and covert operations.

Here is the claim in English, contextualized as part of France's operations against Guinea:

[image]

From E. Schmidt, *Cold War and Decolonization in Guinea, 1946–1958*, 171–172.

The citation for the counterfeiting goes to Roger Faligot and Pascal Krop, *La Piscine: Les Services Secrets Français, 1944–1984* (Paris: Éditions du Seuil, 1985), 246–47, which I do not have on hand.

edit, 2021: Here is the passage in question.

[image]

The quotation seems to be from Col. Tristan Richard, a secret service agent who was confident enough in his own reputation to [sue his own subordinate in 1981, claiming defamation](https://www.lemonde.fr/archives/article/1981/03/11/les-auteurs-de-sdece-service-7-poursuivis-en-diffamation_2713941_1819218.html).